# REST endpoint works as in line script and doesn't work when mentioned as file-Cannot open URL: bundle://200.0:1/rest_CreateMultipleSubtasks.groovy

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I am using this REST endpoint for a fragment and it works perfectly as an inline script.

[image]
Here is my code below and here is a screenshot of the page where I am redirected after clicking on the button. 
[image]

```
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

import CreateMultipleSubtasks.Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks

import com.atlassian.jira.project.Project

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

callSubTaskCreator(httpMethod: "GET", groups: ["jira-users"]) {MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body ->

def log1 = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")

log1.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA223"); 

Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks conf =new Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks()

def MultipleSubtasksHashMap= conf.getSubTaskCreatorHashMap()

String itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL = MultipleSubtasksHashMap["itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL"] as String;

log1.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA223 "+itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL); 

 def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext?.loggedInUser

  def issueId = queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as Long

  Issue myissue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(issueId)

  def issueKey = myissue.getKey()

  def itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL2 = itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL.replaceAll(":1:", issueKey)

  def itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL3 = itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL2.replaceAll(":2:", user.getUsername())

  log1.warn("The rest endpoint has been executed by the user " +user)

  Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL3)).build()

  

}
```

When I specify a file for the code that I refer to in my script editor. Everything fails when I click on the button and I am redirected to an error page as you can see below.

anyone knows what the problem is?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a package declatation at the top of the code so we need **package BulkSplitter** at the top of the code. We need to go to REST endpoint and execute an update. Otherwise, Jira doesn't recognize our changes.

```
package BulkSplitter 
import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import com.atlassian.jira.issue.Issue;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

import org.apache.log4j.Logger

import groovy.transform.BaseScript

import com.onresolve.scriptrunner.runner.rest.common.CustomEndpointDelegate

import javax.ws.rs.core.MultivaluedMap

import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response

import CreateMultipleSubtasks.Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks

import com.atlassian.jira.project.Project

@BaseScript CustomEndpointDelegate delegate

callSubTaskCreator(httpMethod: "GET", groups: ["jira-users"]) {MultivaluedMap queryParams, String body ->

def log1 = Logger.getLogger("atlassian-jira.log")

log1.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA223"); 

Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks conf =new Configuration_CreateMultipleSubtasks()

def MultipleSubtasksHashMap= conf.getSubTaskCreatorHashMap()

String itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL = MultipleSubtasksHashMap["itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL"] as String;

log1.warn("MOUNA CAMELIA223 "+itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL); 

 def user = ComponentAccessor.jiraAuthenticationContext?.loggedInUser

  def issueId = queryParams.getFirst("issueId") as Long

  Issue myissue = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager().getIssueObject(issueId)

  def issueKey = myissue.getKey()

  def itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL2 = itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL.replaceAll(":1:", issueKey)

  def itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL3 = itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL2.replaceAll(":2:", user.getUsername())

  log1.warn("The rest endpoint has been executed by the user " +user)

  Response.temporaryRedirect(URI.create(itracCreatemultiplesubtasksProjectCategoriesURL3)).build()

  

}
```